# Vlookup with Offset

Tags: excel

l'm trying to nest an OFFSET formula within a VLOOKUP but l keep getting #N/A. This is my formula...

=VLOOKUP($B4,OFFSET($F$6,5,5),6,0)

Assume that cells $B4 and $F$6 are called 'CARS'. I want to find total car sales in a year. The 'lookup value' is using CARS but the 'table array' data l want to pull is 5 rows below and 5 columns across from $F$6 hence the Offset formula. I know the OFFSET formula works on it's own but not within the VLOOKUP.

I believe that the 'col index num' (i.e. 6 above) is the issue. I saw a video using something similar but when l apply the same principals it won't work and l can't get my head around this?

Can anyone help? I did try to include a screen shot to help but it wouldn't attach.

Thanks,

M

Comment: the offset returns one cell and you are telling it to return the result from 6 columns over, which is not includes in the range as it is only one cell.

Comment: You do not have enough rep to attach a photo but you can attach a link.  Please do so.

Comment: You probably want to look into the `INDEX()` and `MATCH()` functions and forget about the `OFFSET()` functions.  Just add 5 (+5) to the row and column number that gets returned by the `MATCH()` function.  Check out this link for details: http://www.cruter.com/u/sfk

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I can make the INDEX & MATCH work but using the VLOOKUP with and OFFSET was something l just wanted to work.

Comment: Hi Scott, Could you provide the formula that would work in this instance of VLOOKUP and OFFSET? Thanks again, M.